# How can i Convert left vertical menu to right?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I want to convert this left vertical menu to right vertical menu 
I copy this code: css menu maker
I located the piece of code that causes this error, but do not know how to correct it.

CSS:

/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */

```
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul,
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #F0EFEA;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  background: #407a1e url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #4b8e23), color-stop(1, #407a1e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4b8e23, #407a1e);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #327E04;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 150px;
}
#cssmenu a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
#cssmenu a:link,
#cssmenu a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #4b8e23 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #6ea936), color-stop(1, #4b8e23));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#6ea936, #4b8e23);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub.hover > a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #808080;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: could you describe the isue you are trying to cerrect and provide a fidddle would be great

Comment: how can i convert left vertical menu to right ?

Comment: what have you tried? what issues did you get trying? You are basicaly asking for someone to do this for you and we are not here to work for you but to help you manage. So you shouyld try, get issues, come back here and ask for help on these specific issues...

Comment: here is a fiddle of your code : http://jsfiddle.net/DyjK2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jk2V/1/)

```
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: right;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:right;  
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul,
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -1px;
  right: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #F0EFEA;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  background: #407a1e url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #4b8e23), color-stop(1, #407a1e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4b8e23, #407a1e);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #327E04;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 150px;
}
#cssmenu a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
#cssmenu a:link,
#cssmenu a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #4b8e23 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #6ea936), color-stop(1, #4b8e23));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#6ea936, #4b8e23);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub.hover > a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
  border-color: transparent #808080 transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

good luck

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssss very mush